# Is it possible to return the index of an array with ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use `ng-options` to return the index of an element in an array instead of its value:

the `select` directive:

```
<select ng-model="obj.value" ng-options="v for v in obj.values"></select>
```

which is working fine if the datas are formatted like so:

```
{ "value": "value 3", "values": [ "value 1", "value 2", "value 3", "value 4"] }
```

The problem is the web-service send datas like this:

```
{ "value": 2, "values": [ "value 1", "value 2", "value 3", "value 4"] }
```

Is it possible to modify the directive to :

- by default, select the element which index correspond to `value`
- when the user select an element, return its index (instead of its value)

?

Comment: Please keep in mind, angularjs is model(data) driven. When you want to do a select, it is equivalent to add a ng-model and set the value of the model object. And angularjs automatically does 2-way binding to reflect the change on the UI.

Comment: So it's not possible for the model to be binded to the index instead of the values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've [almost done what you need](http://jsfiddle.net/madhead/kC8eV/), but still one problem:

JS:

```
var demo = angular.module("demo", []);

demo.controller("DemoController", ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.obj = {
        "value": 2,
        "values": [
            "value 1",
            "value 2",
            "value 3",
            "value 4"
        ]
    };
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<body data-ng-app="demo">
    <div data-ng-controller="DemoController">
        <select data-ng-model="obj.value">
            <option data-ng-repeat="i in obj.values"
                    value="{{$index}}"
                    data-ng-selected="$index == obj.value">
                        {{i}}
            </option>
        </select>
        {{obj}}
    </div>
</body>
```

But `obj.value` becomes string after something is selected in dropdown. [A quick fix.](http://jsfiddle.net/madhead/kC8eV/1/)